# Python code not running because I don't have "win32con"

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial for a voice assistant python project and I just tried running it and received the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32con'". I read a post where someone had a similar issue ~13 years ago and somebody mentioned needing to run windows for it, however I'm on Manjaro linux version KDE Plasma 5.23.5 and Kernel 5.15.21-1 64-bit running Python 3.10.2. Does anybody know if this is a software issue and/or a way around it?

for context, I am following this AI voice assistant tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/voice-assistant-using-python/

Comment: "win32con" is part of "Pywin32" module (module especially done for windows OS), try install it by using PIP in your CMD of windows just like this: pip 3.10 install pywin32

Comment: You are apparently trying to do something Windows-specific on your Linux machine.  You haven't given us nearly enough details to even guess at what that might be.

Comment: I'm on Manjaro, so Windows specific modules/techniques won't work for me

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/voice-assistant-using-python/ to create a basic voice assistant for my computer

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify that. Don't put relevant info into comments, it makes your question hard to read and understand.